# how to load json data on start of view controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to fetch data on start of viewcontroller. every time the view controller open it should update the data as per the JSON. I have added all the code in `viewDidLoad()` as well as I have put it in `viewWillAppear()` but it does not load the data . can anyone help me out to know what I can do to load the data everytime the view controller opens.

second question : I have read a lot of solution about this error : `thread 1 exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)` but i don't understand why i am getting this error . it comes at `@iBAction` on click of `Button` and in that button click I am using a delegate to push the data back to the previous viewcontroller

popViewcontroller.swift:

```
protocol DataSendDelegate {
    func sendgetattid(pop_att_id: Int, pop_in_time: String)
}
var delegate: DataSendDelegate? = nil

if statuss == "200" {
    let send_pop_att_id = att_id
    let send_pop_in_time = in_time
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)                                  
    self.delegate?.sendgetattid(pop_att_id: send_pop_att_id, pop_in_time: send_pop_in_time)
}
```

when I get the status as 200 then it gets that error.

attendance.swift:

```
class attendanceViewController: UIViewController , DataSendDelegate {
    func sendgetattid(pop_att_id: Int, pop_in_time: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.inTimeTextField.text = pop_in_time
            self.get_att_id = pop_att_id
            self.in_time_button.isEnabled = false
            self.out_time_button.isEnabled = true
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       if let popVC = segue.destination as? PopUpViewController {
          popVC.popEmailID = att_emp_id
          popVC.delegate = self
       }
    }
}
```

Error:

`EmployeeAttendance[3891:111312] This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.

Stack:(

```
0   Foundation                          0x000000010ddb980a _AssertAutolayoutOnAllowedThreadsOnly + 77

1   Foundation                          0x000000010dbc266a -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 28

2   UIKit                               0x000000010fc000e3 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 855

3   UIKit                               0x000000010fbfdf16 __UIViewWasRemovedFromSuperview + 169

4   UIKit                               0x000000010fbfda07 -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 521

5   UIKit                               0x00000001107a9c5b __46-[UIInputWindowController invalidateInputView]_block_invoke + 127

6   UIKit                               0x000000010fd7a19d -[UIResponder _preserveResponderOverridesWhilePerforming:] + 125

7   UIKit                               0x00000001107a9bd3 -[UIInputWindowController invalidateInputView] + 111

8   UIKit                               0x00000001107aa59d -[UIInputWindowController changeToInputViewSet:] + 222

9   UIKit                               0x00000001107abcbc __43-[UIInputWindowController setInputViewSet:]_block_invoke_2.1494 + 39

10  UIKit                               0x00000001107a2a62 -[UIInputWindowController moveFromPlacement:toPlacement:starting:completion:] + 617

11  UIKit                               0x00000001107abc8f __43-[UIInputWindowController setInputViewSet:]_block_invoke.1493 + 97

12  UIKit                               0x000000011079b208 -[UIInputWindowController performOperations:withTemplateNotificationInfo:] + 46

13  UIKit                               0x00000001107ab81b -[UIInputWindowController setInputViewSet:] + 1336

14  UIKit                               0x00000001107a2450 -[UIInputWindowController performOperations:withAnimationStyle:] + 50

15  UIKit                               0x000000011033f118 -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) setInputViews:animationStyle:] + 1593

16  UIKit                               0x0000000110336f4b -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _reloadInputViewsForResponder:] + 2163

17  UIKit                               0x0000000110340480 -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _preserveInputViewsWithId:animated:reset:] + 498

18  UIKit                               0x000000010fd2d94e -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didStartTransition:] + 910

19  UIKit                               0x000000010fd21475 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 3813

20  UIKit                               0x000000010fd373b4 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 686

21  UIKit                               0x000000010fd386d3 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 150

22  UIKit                               0x000000010ff934e2 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 231

23  UIKit                               0x000000010fc17a6d -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1439

24  QuartzCore                          0x000000011661561c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 159

25  QuartzCore                          0x00000001166197ad _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 401

26  QuartzCore                          0x00000001165a086c _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 364

27  QuartzCore                          0x00000001165cd946 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 500

28  QuartzCore                          0x00000001165cdfbd _ZN2CA11Transaction14release_threadEPv + 213

29  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000113c2b27e _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 534

30  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000113c2afbd _pthread_exit + 79

31  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000113c292ac _pthread_wqthread + 1613

32  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000113c28c4d start_wqthread + 13
```

)`

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let url = URL(string:"http://192.168.0.113/attendance/check_attend.php")

        let parameters = ["emp_id": self.att_emp_id]

        var request = URLRequest(url : url!)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:parameters, options: [])

        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let session = URLSession.shared

        session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

            if let data = data {

                do {

                    let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! Dictionary<String, Any>

                    if let json = json {

                        print("HERE SHOULD BE YOUR JSON \(json)")

                        //var datas = [String:AnyObject]()

                        if let datas = json["data"] as? [String:AnyObject]  , let in_time_Str = datas["in_time"] as? String, let out_time_Str = datas["out_time"] as? String , let grace_Str = datas["grace"] as? String, let signal_Str = datas["signal"] as? String

                        {

                            print("here is attendance Data : \(datas)")

                            print("Here is attendance Signal : \(signal_Str)")

                            //datas = data

                            if in_time_Str != ""

                            {

                                self.server_in_time = in_time_Str

                                print("Here is attendance IN TIME : \(self.server_in_time)")

                            }

                            if out_time_Str != ""

                            {

                                self.server_out_time = out_time_Str

                                print("Here is attendance OUT TIME : \(self.server_out_time)")
                            }
                            if signal_Str == "10" {
                                self.grace_str_time = grace_Str
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    self.out_time_button.isEnabled = false
                                }
                            } else if signal_Str == "01" {
                                self.server_in_time = in_time_Str
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    self.inTimeTextField.text = self.server_in_time
                                    self.in_time_button.isEnabled = false
                                    self.out_time_button.isEnabled = true
                                }
                            } else if signal_Str == "00" {
                                self.server_out_time = out_time_Str   
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {   
                                    self.inTimeTextField.text = self.server_in_time   
                                    self.outTimeTextField.text = self.server_out_time    
                                    self.in_time_button.isEnabled = false    
                                    self.out_time_button.isEnabled = false    
                                }    
                            } else {    
                                print("Error : \(String(describing: error))")    
                            }    
                        }    
                    }    
                }    
            } else {    
                print("Error \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")    
            }    
        }).resume()    
    }
```

Comment: add it in your viewController viewDidAppear and add a activityLoadingView to notify the user when is your app loading

Comment: Also add your json loading code and code where it is getting crashed.

Comment: i have added my code @SharadChauhan

Comment: it worked @ReinierMelian

Comment: but can you check my code to see what is wrong in it . because sometimes i get the error which i have added sometimes it doesnot give me any error but it does not work

Comment: You spelled status as statuss.

Comment: that is not an issue because i have declared that as `statuss` only .that is a string which i am fetching from json .

Comment: it worked only for one time .. now it is not working while debugging it is not entering viewDidAppear @ReinierMelian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where it crashed not clear by your code. But what can I refer is to call self.delegate?.sendgetattid(pop_att_id: send_pop_att_id, pop_in_time: send_pop_in_time) before popping out the view controller. Enclose above in dispatch async call. Hope it helps.

Comment: it is working sometimes and sometimes the error which i have added i get that error . i am not understanding why sometimes it works and sometimes it does not . same is happening with the loading of json at start of view controller sometimes it goes in viewdidappear and sometimes it does not

Comment: Hope the status you are receiving from json. Enclose delegate.yourMethod and navigationController.popViewController inside dispatch async call.

Comment: yes it worked .. hope so it will work everytime . can i know the any suggestion for my first question . i want to load json data to textview everytime viewcontroller opens . it does not fetches the data

Comment: Where are you calling your fetch data api? You said you are triggering in viewWillAppear? Can you please post your code over here?

Comment: i will update my question with the code @Deblina Das

Comment: While debugging . the code does not work after session.datatask . it directly moves out and goes to resume statement

Comment: The completionHandler is executed after the task returns. Put breakpoint to the handler where you have written "if let data = data {....}" Refer the link: https://grokswift.com/completion-handlers-in-swift/